# How to convert a plain Java for-loop to a Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert this code to Java 8 stream?

```
String getFirst(String key) {
    for (Param p : params) {
        if (key.equals(p.getKey())) {
            if (!p.getValues().isEmpty()) {
                return p.getValues().get(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Some IDEs will do this conversion for you. I suggest you see if the IDE will do this for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return params.stream()
  .filter(p -> key.equals(p.getKey())
  .filter(p -> ! p.getValues().isEmpty())
  .map(p -> p.getValues().get(0))
  .findFirst()
  .orElse("");
```

If `p.getValues()` is a `List`, you could shorten it as:

```
return params.stream()
  .filter(p -> key.equals(p.getKey())
  .flatMap(p -> p.getValues().stream())
  .findFirst()
  .orElse("");
```

If it's not important to get the **first** matching value and you are ok with just getting **any** match, replace `findFirst()` with `findAny()`.  It will more clearly mark your intent and, if somebody makes the stream parallel later on, `findAny()` may perform better.

Comment: Two filters could be merged into single predicate for efficiency.